# JSX dismiss an arrow (>) in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

In normal javascript, I can easily add an arrow like:

```
<button>Next > </button>
```

but I try that is JSX, the arrow will be ignored/dismissed. Hmm is there any way I can enable that?

Comment: Normal JSX will not ignore  the arrow ` >`  check your button style for any width  applied to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because JSX works directly with HTML so you would need to use HTML symbol codes for reserved letters.

You could use

```
<button>Next &gt; </button>
```

or

```
<button>Next &#62; </button>
```

Check out the full list here:
http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you want a > output you should HTML encode this as &gt

```
<button>Next &gt </button>
```